# Get all the document libraries where IsContentTypeAllowed is enabled

Tags: document-library, content-type, powershell

I am using this PowerShell code to get a list of document libraries where allow content type is enabled. But it does not return anything.

```
Get-SPWeb http://intranet.site.net |
   Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
   Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary" -and
          -not $_.Hidden } |
   Select -ExpandProperty Items |
   Where { $_["IsContentTypeAllowed"] -eq "True" } |
   Select Name, url
```

Comment: I tried AllowContentTypes -eq "True" or "1" and no result yielded

Comment: Welcome to the SharePoint Stack Exchange site.  You should add your comment as an edit to your question.  You can click the edit link below your question to do so.

Comment: I cannot try atm, but does `Where { $_.IsContentTypeAllowed -eq "True" }` work ? You can also try `-eq $true` (as I don't know what it must return). And finally, as @Amal Hashim mentionned below, care about your final `| Select`, maybe Name doesn't return anything (maybe try a `| fl` ?). As you didn't say if you got error or just nothing.

Comment: it does not throw any error. PS C:\Powershell> .\GetAllDocLibs.ps1
PS C:\Powershell> .\GetAllDocLibs.ps1
PS C:\Powershell>

Comment: without the iscontenttypeallowed test, do you have any results ? You should test every single condition one by one

Comment: strange without the iscontenttypeallowed is does not return any data.

Comment: Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary"  works but after adding the contenttype line i get following error. unable to index into an object of type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works but I am getting so many noises like pages, image, documents, site assets and many other libraries with it. I need to add more code to exclude built in libraries. I end up re-doing the code and the following code is good enough for my requirements.

```
#For Output file generation
$OutputFN = "Libraries.csv"
#delete the file, If already exist!
if (Test-Path $OutputFN)
 {
    Remove-Item $OutputFN
 }
#Write the CSV Headers
Add-Content $OutputFN "Web URL, Site Name, Library Name"


$systemlibs =@("Converted Forms", "Customized Reports", "Documents", "Form Templates",  
                              "Images", "List Template Gallery", "Master Page Gallery", "Pages",  
                               "Reporting Templates", "Site Assets", "Site Collection Documents", 
                               "Site Collection Images", "Site Pages", "Solution Gallery",  
                               "Style Library", "Theme Gallery", "Web Part Gallery", "wfpub")

#Get the Site collection 
$Site= Get-SPSite "http://intranet.webapp.home"
$spWebApp = $Site.WebApplication
foreach($allSites in $spWebApp.Sites)
{
       #Loop throuh all Sub Sites
       foreach($Web in $allSites.AllWebs)
       {
        #Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------"
        #Write-Host "Site Name: '$($web.Title)' at $($web.URL)"
        #Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------"
        foreach($list in $Web.Lists)
        {
            if($list.BaseTemplate -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $list.AllowContentTypes -eq $true)

            {
                if(-not ($systemlibs -Contains $list.Title))
                {
                    #Write-Host "$($web.URL), $($web.Title), $($list.Title)" 
                    $content = $web.URL + "," + $web.Title +"," + $list.Title
                    add-content $OutputFN $content
                }
            }
        }
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Get-SPWeb http://intranet.site.net |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
Where { $_.BaseTemplate -eq "SPDocumentLibrary" -and
      -not $_.Hidden -and $_["ContentTypesEnabled"] -eq "True" } |
Select Title, Url
```

Comment: no results returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Get-SPWeb http://intranet.site.net |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
Where { $_.BaseTemplate -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Hidden -eq $false -and $_.ContentTypesEnabled -eq $true}|
Select Title, RootFolder
```

Also note that there is no property called `Url`in `SPList`. Use `RootFolder` of `SPList` along with `SPWeb.Url` to get the Url of the list.